# Any eMail client for Android with good signatures (bottom text) management?

Tags: email-client

Desktop software (Outlook, ThunderBird, The Bat!... etc) use to have eMail client programs capable of adding a **signature** (final text, like "Best Wishes", "Phone number:..."... etc) to each new (and replied) composed email message.
That is not usual on Android apps, and you rather get something like:

> Hello World.
>
> ---
>
> Sent from K-9 eMail client for Android.

Could you please suggest me any **eMail client** app for **Android** that allows me to create/import minimally **complex texts for signatures** on my eMail messages?

**Desired features**:

- Fonts management.
- Graphics.
- Links.

**Open source** solutions preferred. Payment options accepted.

Comment: certainly you can change the signature in [K-9 Mail](https://k9mail.github.io/), create different ones for more identities and manage them easily! ...but no idea if other than plain text is possible (because i just use plain text to play it safe).

Answer (score 1):

With **MailDroid** you can technically do it. Though they don't have everything supported in their own Signature editor, they allow you to add Raw HTML code as a signature! That virtually allows you to anything.

Even if you don't know how to write HTML, you can easily create something nice for free with services like [**www.mysignature.io**](http://www.mysignature.io), and then use the finished HTML code in MailDroid.

They have a [**free version**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maildroid&hl=en), and a [**Pro version**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maildroid.pro&hl=en) without ads and some additional features.

To add the HTML code you go into **Settings**>**Compose**>**Signature**. Choose the account you want to add it to and click the three dots on the upper-right side and select **Add raw HTML signature**. Then open the newly added empty signature and paste in the HTML code you have.

Comment: Is it supposed to allow graphics embedding on that HTML code?

Comment: If it has the proper image URL in the HTML code then yes.

Comment: Linking a external image via URL is not embedding it inside the email message.

Comment: Are you talking about embedded whole image data? I assume it does but I haven't tried.

Comment: I have installed MailDroid, and it allows adding images on signatures. A flaw: as for today (v4.81), these images fail when trying to include URL links (I have notified the author). I have tested the RAW HTML method too, and it works, but if you want to embed images, you should use the base64 equivalent, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329400/1461017 . Help with conversion to base 64 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16918665/1461017 . Thanks you, Yisroel Tech.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Crivens, [Samsung EMAIL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.email.provider&hl=en) is a very decent mail client on the Play Store. It has all options of a good client except the Archive gesture (achieved with swipe & move). It has a very sofisticated rich text editor for that, but don't let you write down HTML directly over it. Insted, you have to open your HTML signature on Chrome and copy/paste the rendered page over the editor. All data is retained: general structure, links, styles... No memory hogs and no excesive data leaks by the time I'm writing this, mostly because I use push on all my accounts.

As for now, I'm looking for an email client with HTML signature (check) AND the Archive gesture (still looking for). I'll use it until I find what I really looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use Nine Folders and find it is very feature rich.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3

Answer (score 0):

I use the Samsung Email app. Not sure if available for other devices, but mine came installed on my S8+. I tried loads of other apps, inc Outlook and Gmail, but couldn't get the HTML signature. Pasted into Samsung Email app perfectly fine. Only downside is it seemed to use up a lot of battery, but with some time management in the settings (work Emails only in the day and less regularly in the night , private Emails less regularly full stop) it's a lot better.

Comment: Could you please add some more exact reference to this software in order we can find and eventually test it?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.email.provider